# Is there a way to number records extracted .

Tags: xquery

I need to extract data from my relational database as XML, and I need to assign a number to each record that I extract. I wrote the following XQuery...

```
<myRecords> {
    let $i := 0
    for $Territories in collection("Northwind.dbo.Territories")/Territories
    let $i := $i + 1
    return
        <territory rec_count="{$i}">
            {$Territories/TerritoryDescription/text()}
        </territory>
} </myRecords>
```

... I don't get the result I expected:

```
<myRecords>
    <territory rec_count="1">Westboro</territory>
    <territory rec_count="1">Bedford</territory>
    <territory rec_count="1">Georgetown</territory>
…
```

The record number isn't incremented. Why?

XQuery is a functional language without side effects — you can't really create a notion of state in XQuery as you might in Java or C#, for example. In some cases, you can simulate state using a recursive function, but to solve this problem there is a much simpler solution: you can use a positional variable. Here's the XQuery:

```
<myRecords> {
    for $Territories at $i in collection("Northwind.dbo.Territories")/Territories
    return
        <territory rec_count="{$i}">
            {$Territories/TerritoryDescription/text()}
        </territory>
} </myRecords>
```

And here's the (hoped-for) result:

```
<myRecords>
    <territory rec_count="1">Westboro</territory>
    <territory rec_count="2">Bedford</territory>
    <territory rec_count="3">Georgetow</territory>
…
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a bit to Dimitre's answer, here's how to do what you're trying to do:

```
<myRecords> {
  for $Territories at $i in collection("Northwind.dbo.Territories")/Territories
  return
    <territory rec_count="{$i}">
      {$Territories/TerritoryDescription/text()}
    </territory>
} </myRecords>
```

As Dimitre noted, a let inside a for does not preserve the value with each iteration. The at clause of the for will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> let $i := 0
>      for $Territories in collection("Northwind.dbo.Territories")/Territories
>      let $i := $i + 1
>      return
> ```

In the inner `let` a *new* variable named `i` is created.

It is defined to have the value of the *outer* `$i` plus one: that is `0 + 1`, which gives `1`.